# How To Namespace Or Prefix Semantic UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

Can anyone help me in how to namespace(prefix) everything in [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) for example prefix `"button"` class to `"my-prefix-button"` class?

Also, will this modification affect the JavaScript modules work? For example Accordion, Modal, Popup and all the other modules, if the answer is yes then how to fix it?

**Please if you want to use Less or SASS in your answer to achieve that, detail your answer step by step because I am really new to these two fields.**

Comment: I have removed the thanks note as it is considered as fluff and is not required. I have also made a few other minor edits to the content.

Comment: I just looked at the LESS sources and, unfortunarely, Semantic UI doesn't offer a way to do this. Perhaps you could share your use case with us so that we can offer some possible alternative.

Comment: @fstanis Thank you. I just created a form for my WordPress plugin using Semantic UI and and I liked it and I decided to use all the Semantic UI components in my plugins but when I switched my theme I got shocked! everytime I switch my theme the form style change! I think   becase Semantic UI doesn't offer this functionality I'll looking for another css&js framework.

Comment: I've added an answer with jlukic's (author and lead developer of Semantic UI) stance on this and his reason for not including this feature. Since Semantic UI is a lot more than just a CSS & JS framework, if you just want to make your forms simple & clean, you might want to check out [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/forms/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already mentioned in the comments that this is impossible, but I've meanwhile found an [official statement from the author](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1701) regarding this, so I'll copy it here for the sake of closure to this question:

> I don't plan on releasing anything like this.
>
> Part of the goal of Semantic is simplifying front end codebases. This
>   would be another step towards obfuscation. It may be a requirement for
>   certain use cases, but I don't think I want to convince developers
>   this is a necessary path for interoperability.

Answer (score 7):

Even I picked another answer to my question(because my question talking about another kind of prefixing and currently that is impossible and the reason in the answer that I picked) but here is what I did to prefix it and it worked for me.

I used less to namespace it with another class like the following:

```
.my-class {
  @import (less) url("button.min.css");
  @import (less) url("message.min.css");
  @import (less) url("form.min.css");
  @import (less) url("table.min.css");
}
```